# How can I hide this div while the animation is in progress?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#content-display').offset().top}, function () {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }, 'slow');
```

JSHint likes it but I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slow'` in console.

Comment: Why don't show it first then animate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arguments are out of order:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#content-display').offset().top}, 'slow', function () {
    $("#loading").show();
});
```

From the [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) documentation:

> .animate( **properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete]**)

However if you want to do what your title states, you would want to `show` the div *before* the animation, and then hide it afterwards:

```
$("#loading").show();
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#content-display').offset().top}, function () {
    $("#loading").hide();
}, 'slow');
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. And yea, I actually meant hide, I edited the question to reflect what I intended. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around.. the syntax of animate function is

animate(properties, duration, function)

Please change it to

`$('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#content-display').offset().top}, 'slow', function () {
        $("#loading").show();
    });`